# Installing HLDS Update Tool on Ubuntu server

Tags: ubuntu

I am trying to install a Counter-Strike: Source server on my Ubuntu box.
I am using the HLDS tool in the guide [here](http://llbb.wordpress.com/2007/02/20/installing-hlds-on-linux/).

I have downloaded `hldsupdatetool.bin` to my home directory (`/home/chris/cssserver/hldsupdatetool.bin`) and run the commands it's told me to, but the file never seems to run. Here's my terminal:

```
chris@ks395362:~/cssserver$ wget http://storefront.steampowered.com/download/hldsupdatetool.bin
--2012-07-15 21:29:56--  http://storefront.steampowered.com/download/hldsupdatetool.bin
Resolving storefront.steampowered.com... 87.248.210.253, 87.248.210.254
Connecting to storefront.steampowered.com|87.248.210.253|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 3513408 (3.4M) [application/octet-stream]
Saving to: `hldsupdatetool.bin'

100%[======================================>] 3,513,408   10.4M/s   in 0.3s

2012-07-15 21:29:57 (10.4 MB/s) - `hldsupdatetool.bin' saved [3513408/3513408]

chris@ks395362:~/cssserver$ sudo chmod +x hldsupdatetool.bin
chris@ks395362:~/cssserver$ sudo ./hldsupdatetool.bin
chris@ks395362:~/cssserver$ ls
hldsupdatetool.bin
chris@ks395362:~/cssserver$ file hldsupdatetool.bin
hldsupdatetool.bin: ELF 32-bit LSB executable, Intel 80386, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), stripped
```

The binary is meant to extract steam into that directory when it's run, but it doesn't do anything. If I just run `./hldsupdatetool.bin` without `sudo` I get this error:

```
-sh: ./hldsupdatetool.bin: No such file or directory
```

What gives?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, you should *not* run this tool with `sudo`.

Second, it's most likely that you are on a 64-bit system, but this is a 32-bit binary. Try installing the 32-bit compatibility libraries:

```
sudo apt-get install ia32-libs
```

After that, try again with:

```
./hldsupdatetool.bin
```

If it still refuses to start, run this command and paste the output in your original question:

```
ldd ./hldsupdatetool.bin
```

Comment: Thanks, that's the reason. However, when I try to install `ia32-libs` it fails because it needs a dependancy called `lib32v4l-0 (>= 0.5.0)`, then I try to install that I get a dependency error saying: `Depends: libv4l-0 (= 0.8.0-1) but 0.8.5-3ubuntu2 is to be installed`

Comment: That's a separate question. :) But to answer it, you should do `sudo apt-get update; sudo apt-get upgrade` first.

Comment: That didn't fix it, but as you said that's a whole other question. Thanks for answering this one :)

Comment: @MarkTwaign Time to upgrade to 12.04 perhaps? :)

Comment: My server host offers it but says it's in beta, would it not be better to run a stable version?

Comment: Ubuntu 12.04 was released last April. I have no idea what they're talking about.

Answer (score 0):

The package `ia32-libs` has been expanded to include a lot more stuff than is needed **as of 12.04**. **Installing only `lib32objc3` seems to work though.** Tested on fresh install of **12.04**.